# change the language of a plugin "Ultimate member"

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ultimate-member

I would like change the plugin "Ultimate member" language to french
I make a lot of researches but I don't find an answer
can someone help me please ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to translate the plugin?

Comment: yes , i mean that i would  change the default words to another language without manually changing them @justkidding96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this plugin [loco translate](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) then translate the plugin or theme you want.

Comment: New translations template for "Ultimate Member"

Source files to scan: 280 (1.94 MB on disk) Excludes 2 files over 100 KB.
Strings will be extracted to: plugins/ultimate-member/languages/ultimate-member.pot 

i can't create a new template to change the language

Comment: Try to change the location of the template to point in your theme instead of in the plugin folder.

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: it is impossible to create a new one 
as I show you in the first comment

Comment: You can edit that template then and change the location?

Comment: A i see, so the plugin have already a template. So from that template you need to create a new language and translate the strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: How I can apply a language
I did the translation but I do not find how to apply the new language

Answer (score 0):

you should rename the .mo and .po files as the following 
ultimatemember-ar.po  to ultimate-member-ar.po 
ultimatemember-ar.mo  to ultimate-member-ar.mo

you should add (-) between ultimate and member